# Xcode won't let me upload my app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an iOS app created with Cordova, and have just paid my $99 to apple to upload it to the App Store. I've created the app archive, but in the Organizer `Upload to App Store…` is grayed out, and I've got "Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Developer Program."

[image]

Here is my account in preferences, which I have tried removing and re-adding

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you followed [Uploading Your App to iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html)? Maybe the build is with the wrong provisioning profile.

Comment: Sounds like your build target doesn't point to any developer teams.

Comment: Blah, looks like I got a downvote on my question. I mean, I've got a working app on my phone, and uploading to the App Store requires working my way thought like 6 different mazes blindfolded. There is a ton of Apple documentation, but it's thousands of pages and they're loooooong and 99% of them contain stuff I've either already done or don't need.

FWIW, the problem seems to be that in my App settings I had the wrong profile selected; i.e., the free profile and not the new paid one. Sheesh.

Comment: Going to Preferences > Accounts and clicking "View Details" solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I see you have two Team entries. I believe the issue might be because you have the "Personal Team" option selected under your Project settings page.

In Xcode, in the Filesystem sidebar, select the Project node, select your main Target, and choose the non-Personal Team entry. Ensure you have a device selected so you can provision it, then rebuild and rearchive, then it should work.

Comment: In my case, it worked after selecting the team 'None' first and selecting the correct team again.

Comment: Awesome! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What happened to work for me was to "Enable Bitcode: Yes" under Build Options in my project target in Xcode. With that enabled I was able to upload to app store via the Application Loader.

I had to archive the project and export with bitcode attached.

I know this is way past the time for the original post, but hopefully it can help someone looking for a similar solution.