# Personal Team is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, xcode11

I am trying to upload the app to app store but getting this error on validating the app or distribution.

> Team "Username (Personal Team)" is not enrolled in the Apple
>   Developer Program. Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple
>   Developer Program. Visit https://developer.apple.com/account to
>   enroll.

I am new iOS development and app built with the react native framework and publishing the app using XCode 11.2.1. I am using a team member account as an app manager.

I find this [Apple Developer link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1915/_index.html) for the known issue but I don't understand the solution they are providing. Can any body explain it.

Comment: personal team cant be added , so have you tried selecting the normal team. Like suppose XYZ rather than XYZ(Personal team)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630860/xcode-wont-let-me-upload-my-app
and have you enrolled in the apple dveloper program?

Comment: How can I add normal team? I am seeing only my account with personal team token.

Comment: I am an App Manager and account holder is enrolled in the apple developer program.

Comment: Make sure that you have logged in to your developer account in Xcode settings and installed the required signing certificates. Your personal team is the free team linked to your Apple ID.

Comment: The apple developer program is something that forces app user's to pay $100 a year in order to publish apps to the app store. If you haven't signed up for it under your apple id then you're not allowed to to publish apps. Just in case you don't know already.

Answer (score 0):

You convert your account personal team to individual team then works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).